# CN1: Write to a file created in the old GUI builder and read it

Tags: codenameone

So, I created a .txt file in the old GUI builder under the data section. How can I add a text to this file and read it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answer @Shai Almog.

I solved it using the [Preferences API](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/io/Preferences.html). Since I need to save tokens, this was the best way to do it:

```
// save a token to storage
Preferences.set("token", myToken);

// get the token from storage or null if it isn't there
String token = Preferences.get("token", null);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a resource file, not the old GUI builder.

You can't modify files in the resource file as they can't be written. Furthermore, these files are packaged in the JAR/APP which is a read only file on the device.

You can extract the file to a writable place in storage/file system and work with the file there.

You can read more about `Storage`/`FileSystemStorage` [here](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/files-storage-networking.html).

Comment: Another question: How can I convert the project from the old GUI builder to the new one?

Comment: There used to be a tool to do that but we removed it as it no longer works once we moved to autolayout